# Encrypting and Decrypting data on iOS

Tags: ios, node.js, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I am working on an iOS application where a user will have an encryption key and I want to be able:

1. create an encryption/decrption key
2. encrypt data
3. decrypt data

I have no idea how to do either because I have never worked with iOS encryption before.

Thank you

P.S. The server I am using to send the encrypted data back and forth is a Node.JS if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is details on the `CommonCrypto` module of the `Security.framework` for iOS. If you want a shortcut, [here is a NSData category](https://github.com/wei8/NSData_AES) that performs AES encryption and decryption.